# How to add a column of type RDD[Int] to RDD[Vector]

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Let's say we have a variable var1 of type
`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]`
and another variable var2 of type
`org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int]`
both of them have same number of rows.

what I want is add var2 as new column to var1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve your goal is to do this:

```
vv.zip(ii).map( t => Vectors.dense(t._1.toArray ++ Array(t._2.toDouble) ) )
```

where `vv` is you `RDD[Vector]` and `ii` is your `RDD[Int]`. Maybe it's not the most efficient way, but it's the easiest one.